# How to do random sample from ff object

Tags: r, dplyr, sample, ff

I want to extract the number of 1000 values from large size of `ff` object in R.

I have tried `sample_frac` from `dplyr` package, but this results in error as below;

> Error: `tbl` must be a data frame, not a `ffdf` object

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ffbase2 package. It adds the `dplyr` interface to `ff` object

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("edwindj/ffbase2")
```

And read `ff` object as `tbl` with `tbl_ffdf` function.

```
iris_f <- tbl_ffdf(iris)

species <- 
   iris_f %>%
   group_by(Species) %>%
   summarise(petal_width = sum(Petal.Width))
```

Comment: When I used devtools::install_github("edwindj/ffbase2"), I came across the error as below;

package ‘backports’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked Error: (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘backports’ In addition: Warning messages: 1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) : skipping pax global extended headers 2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) : skipping pax global extended headers 3: In is.na(remote_deps$package) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL' What should I do with this?

Comment: Hi, it worked by re-installing backports! Thank you very much for your help.